# можно ли заполнить матрицу имея 2 массива и словарь составленный из них?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, машинное-обучение, обработка-данных

есть матрица построенная по такому принципу

```
import numpy as np

a1=['DD2', 'DD1', 'SB1', 'VT3', 'VT1', 'SNP1', 'C6', 'R1', 'R2', 'C5', 'R3', 'C4', 'R4', 'C2', 'C8', 'R7']

a2=['N162848 ', 'N162003 ', '114 ', '107 ', 'N162820 ', 'N163444 ']

a3={'N162848 ': ['DD2', 'DD2'], 'N162003 ': ['DD1', 'DD1'], '114 ': ['DD2', 'DD1', 'SB1', 'VT3', 'VT1', 'SNP1', 'C6', 'R1', 'R2', 'SNP1'],
    '107 ': ['DD2', 'DD1', 'C6', 'C5', 'SNP1'],
    'N162820 ': ['R3', 'DD2', 'DD1', 'R1', 'C4', 'R4', 'C2'], 'N163444 ': ['DD2', 'C8', 'R7']}

mat=np.zeros((len(a1),len(a2)))

print(mat)
```

и есть словарь составленный из этих списков, вопрос такой: можно ли как то заполнить матрицу 1 и 0 при условии в значении ключа присутствует такой то элемент то на соответствующей этому элементу и ключу позиции матрицы ставится 1 иначе 0, или может я вообще зря решил всё это пробовать делать через словарь?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь реализовать "one hot encoding"?

Comment: @MaxU   через словарь я  показал принадлежность элементов к ключам, матрица должна выглядеть так: значения осей должны быть значениями первых двух массивов и после по словарю должно проверяться условие к примеру в 1 ключе(N162848) есть значение DD2 и это значит что в матрице на позиции [0,0] должна поставиться единица, а к примеру в ключе(N163444) есть  3 элемента, значит в матрице на позициях  [5,0], [5, 14], [5, 15] должны стоять тоже  единицы, вот только можно ли так сделать или нет я пока не нашёл

Comment: У вас исходные данные именно в таком виде - в виде словаря заданы или это вы их уже преобразовали? Спрашиваю потому, что есть подозрение, что построить это по исходным данным будет проще...

Comment: @MaxU исходные данные вообще в текстовом файле который я считал и разбил то что в нем на массивы

Comment: я не понимаю по какому принципу вы собрали словарь `a3` из `a1` и `a2` - можете пояснить? Будет гораздо проще если вы приведете небольшой (3-5 записей) пример исходных данных (как в текстовом файле) и то что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: @MaxU в файле такая запись, точка с запятой это конец строки

N162848  DD2('3) DD2('5);
N162003  DD1('5) DD1('3);
114      DD2('14) DD1('14) SB1('2) VT3('2) VT1('2) SNP1('1) C6('2) R1('2),
          R2('2) SNP1('7);
107      DD2('7) DD1('7) C6('1) C5('1) SNP1('6);
N162820  R3('1) DD2('6),
   DD1('3) R1('2) C4('2),
   R4('6) C2('4);
N163444  DD2('9) C8('2) R7('2);

Comment: @MaxU это файл коммутационной схемы в виде списка соединений, и матрица строится по одной оси это первые элементы строки(номера узлов) а по второй оси это названия элементов входящих в это строку и те элементы которые входят по этим координатам ставятся единицы. вот как то так. может я вообще зря делал все эти массивы и можно просто после регулярных выражений сразу заполнять матрицу?

Comment: ага, уже становиться понятнее и легче обработать... Значения в скобках нужно отбросить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это классическая задача ([one hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f)) преобразования данных для "скармливания" их алгоритмам предсказаний и/или машинного обучения.

Исходный файл:

```
N162848 DD2('3) DD2('5)
N162003 DD1('5) DD1('3)
114 DD2('14) DD1('14) SB1('2) VT3('2) VT1('2) SNP1('1) C6('2) R1('2), R2('2) SNP1('7)
107 DD2('7) DD1('7) C6('1) C5('1) SNP1('6)
N162820 R3('1) DD2('6), DD1('3) R1('2) C4('2), R4('6) C2('4)
N163444 DD2('9) C8('2) R7('2)
```

Решение с использованием Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

fn = r'C:\Temp\735046.txt'    
df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep='~', names=['line'])
# parse 'line' column into index and the rest (data)
df[['idx','data']] = df['line'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
# get rid of the `line` column
df = df.drop('line',1)
# clean data
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace('(?:\([^\)]*\)|,)','')
```

Получился следующий DataFrame:

```
In [299]: df
Out[299]:
       idx                                    data
0  N162848                                 DD2 DD2
1  N162003                                 DD1 DD1
2      114  DD2 DD1 SB1 VT3 VT1 SNP1 C6 R1 R2 SNP1
3      107                      DD2 DD1 C6 C5 SNP1
4  N162820                  R3 DD2 DD1 R1 C4 R4 C2
5  N163444                               DD2 C8 R7
```

Теперь можно воспользоваться [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
In [300]: new = df.set_index('idx')['data'].str.get_dummies(' ')

In [301]: new
Out[301]:
         C2  C4  C5  C6  C8  DD1  DD2  R1  R2  R3  R4  R7  SB1  SNP1  VT1  VT3
idx
N162848   0   0   0   0   0    0    1   0   0   0   0   0    0     0    0    0
N162003   0   0   0   0   0    1    0   0   0   0   0   0    0     0    0    0
114       0   0   0   1   0    1    1   1   1   0   0   0    1     1    1    1
107       0   0   1   1   0    1    1   0   0   0   0   0    0     1    0    0
N162820   1   1   0   0   0    1    1   1   0   1   1   0    0     0    0    0
N163444   0   0   0   0   1    0    1   0   0   0   0   1    0     0    0    0
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ren, пожалуйста :)